# Trying to convert a decimal to datetime either in SQL Server or C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, decimal, system.data.sqlite

I have this decimal `411409629.172566` and it equals `01/14/2014`. I'm working on converting some data from a competitor software and in there SQLite DB, the dates are stored as decimals like that.

In there software the date is what I put above. I have been trying to figure this date out for a couple days now. how do I convert that decimal to that date?

Comment: how Decimal "411409629.172566" and "01/14/2014" can be equal, give bit more details.

Comment: You might want to provide some other dates to help figure out the correspondence - that is not a standard SQLite date format for 2014-01-14, nor is it Unix time.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to represent DateTime using a decimal.
One of which is discussed in the solution given here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690372/net-convert-datetime-to-decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following prints "1/14/2014" in my console :

```
new DateTime(2001, 1, 1).AddSeconds(411409629.172566).ToShortDateString()
```

or using equivalent SQL server syntax :

```
select dateadd(ss, 411409629.172566, '01-01-2001') as 'date'
```

... but without more samples we can't be sure this always do the correct conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
System.DateTime dt = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(yourDecimalValue);
```